# Return the list of selected items, in the CheckBox, to the TabBar main screen Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app with two tabs. One for the "all items" list and second for the "favourite/saved items". The second tab has a `FAB` and text written "Add your favorite items here" inside the `children` of the `Column` widget. So when the `FAB` is clicked, Navigator.push() works and triggers a second screen for "selecting favorite items" by the use of `CheckBox` widget. I've made an empty list `_saved` (its actually a `Set` to avoid duplicates) to store the items that are to be selected. And in the 'select favorite items screen' there is also a `FAB`, which when clicked, Navigator.pop() works and **SHOULD RETURN THE `_saved` LIST**. And this is the only problem I'm facing. I'm just not able to implement it. 
Also as I mentioned above some text is written in the "Saved Items" tab, I want to build something like
"If items selected, just show the items and not the (before mentioned) Text! If none selected anything, just return the Text."

You guys can check the entire code [here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp).
The code where I'm facing issues:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
 }

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Add Your Favorite Sites Here!❤',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 150, color: Colors.blue[100]),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 250),
    FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FavoriteList(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ],
);
   }
  }

//The Favorite List Code:
final Set _saved = Set();

class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
 }

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Add to Favorites!'),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red),
  // backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 53,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          checkColor: Colors.white,
          // value: _saved.contains(context), // changed
          value: _saved.contains(index),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              // isChecked = val;           // changed
              // if(val == true){           // changed
              //   _saved.add(context);     // changed
              // } else{                    // changed
              //   _saved.remove(context);  // changed
              // }                          // changed
              if (val == true) {
                _saved.add(index);
              } else {
                _saved.remove(index);
              }
            });
          },
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Text(nameOfSite[index]),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    foregroundColor: Colors.red,
    child: Icon(Icons.check),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop(context, _saved);
    },
  ),
);
  }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is demo code, you can make your customize code using below code

```
class checkModel{
  String nameOfSite;
  bool isCheck;

  checkModel(this.nameOfSite, this.isCheck);

}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<checkModel> _list = new List();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _list.add(checkModel("title1", false));
    _list.add(checkModel("title2", false));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body:  ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {


          return CheckboxListTile(
            activeColor: Colors.red,
            checkColor: Colors.white,
            // value: _saved.contains(context), // changed
            value: _list[index].isCheck,
            onChanged: (val) {
              print("object  ${val}");
              setState(() {
                _list[index].isCheck = val;
              });
            },
            title: Text(_list[index].nameOfSite),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Navigator.push(
 context,
 MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => FavoriteList(),
 ),
);
```

With:

```
Navigator.push<Set>(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => FavoriteList(),
  ),
).then((Set _saved){
    print(_saved);
});
```

And see logs, you have the `Set` of saved items.